# SQL Server retrieve list of rows inside another list of rows from database

Tags: sql-server, foreign-keys, sql-view, data-retrieval, multiple-records

This might sound confusing and easy also. But I tried a few ways and it didn't work

Now i have a table `User` with these columns

- Id
- UserId
- FileId
- Text

and another table `File`

- Id
- Filename

and a 3rd table `UserDetails`

- Id
- Name
- LastName

`User` & `File` are linked using foreign key `FileId` in matching to `Id`
similarly `User` and `UserDetails` are linked with foreign key `UserId` and `Id`.

So I created a view in SQL:

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[vw_NewView] AS
    SELECT 
        U.Text as Text,
        UD.Name + ' ' + UD.LastName AS FullName
    FROM 
        User U
    LEFT OUTER JOIN 
        dbo.UserDetails UD on UD.Id = U.UserId
```

Now I get a result set:

```
Text     FullName
entry 1  NAme1
entry 2  Name2
```

Note: each `User` will be associated with one `UserDetails`, i.e. `User` has a one-to-one relationship with `Userdetails`.

But `User` has a one-to-many relationship with `File`, so every `User` can have multiple files.

How can I retrieve these files for each user?

Something like this

```
Text     FullName   FileName 
entry 1  NAme1      File1
                    File2 
entry 2  Name2      File1
                    File2
                    File3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used `Stuff` to get the desired output, Below is the code.

```
 CREATE VIEW [dbo].[vw_NewView] AS
    SELECT 
        U.Text as Text,
        UD.Name + ' ' + UD.LastName AS FullName,
     SUBSTRING(
            (
                SELECT ','+CAST(U.Id AS VARCHAR) +'_'+F.FileName  AS [text()]
                FROM File F
                WHERE  U.Id = F.NoteId
                ORDER BY U.Id
                FOR XML PATH ('')
            ), 2, 1000) [FileName]
    FROM 
        User U
    LEFT OUTER JOIN 
        dbo.File F on UD.Id = U.NoteId

    GO
```

This worked For me. Got my answer as a string of comma separated values.

output:

```
Text     FullName   FileName 
entry 1  NAme1      File1,File2 
entry 2  Name2      File1,File2,File3
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[vw_NewView] AS
    SELECT
        [Text] = CASE WHEN RowNum = 1 THEN [Text] END,
        FullName = CASE WHEN RowNum = 1 THEN Name + ' ' + LastName END,
        [File]
    FROM (
        SELECT 
            U.[Text],
            UD.Name,
            UD.LastName,
            F.[File],
            RowNum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY UserId ORDER BY FileID)
        FROM dbo.[User] U
        LEFT JOIN dbo.UserDetails UD on UD.Id = U.UserId
        LEFT JOIN dbo.[File] F ON F.FileID = UD.FileID
    ) t
```

Comment: Hey Devart! thanks for the code, but I would appreciate if you could explain what you have done.. as I am clueless.
why have you put "[]" around Text and File. Please guide further.

Comment: First of all, please check about `ROW_COUNT`... we are just count rows by each user and provide values only for first row. `[]` just a good code style... use a quota for system words like `table`, `column`, `text`, etc

Comment: Hey this didnt exactly work the way i wanted but thanks. :)